# How to design database model and use save method of JpaRepository to save entity if an entity has List<Items> in it?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, database-design, spring-data-jpa

JAVA SPRING :I am exploring JPA and am not sure of optimized way to design db and using save() of repository to save entity data right away into DB. Specifically, I have a basic class viz. Movie -

```
package com.kurshit.moviesmgr.vo;
import java.util.List;
public class Movie {
    long movieId;
    String title;
    String yearOfRelease;
    List<String> genere;

    public Movie(long movieId, String title, String yearOfRelease, List<String> genere) {
        super();
        this.movieId = movieId;
        this.title = title;
        this.yearOfRelease = yearOfRelease;
        this.genere = genere;
    }

    public Movie() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public long getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public void setMovieId(long movieId) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getYearOfRelease() {
        return yearOfRelease;
    }

    public void setYearOfRelease(String yearOfRelease) {
        this.yearOfRelease = yearOfRelease;
    }

    public List<String> getGenere() {
        return genere;
    }

    public void setGenere(List<String> genere) {
        this.genere = genere;
    }
}
```

Each movie has list of Genere - List- it falls under, like - Action, Comedy, etc.

I am trying to create an interface that extends JpaRepository and use the inbuilt save method to save the Movie Data into DB.

I am not sure about how I should design my DB - As in, Questions like - 
 1. Shall I create two different tables for Movie and Genere wherein Movie table references to Genere ?
2. Shall I create just onw table and store all Genere's list as a single CSV in one column ?
3. Can I use repository's save() right away to save and map this data into respective tables.

Would really appreciate if someone can share any sources or sample code to refer or can offer any help.

Thanks much!

Comment: Unless you really need to order your genres, you should use a `Set` instead of `List`. Using a `List` includes ordering data in the database which is usually unnecessary.

Comment: Please, don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should search look up @Entity annotation so that you can tell your ORM to create the necesary table for that entity.
Secondly, you need to ask yourself, how this application will work. It would be best in my opinion to create a genre entity as well, linked to Movie through a @ManyToMany relationship. 
Try looking over the simple entity example here
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

First variant - with 'genre' as enum (if your genre is a fixed list):

```
@Data // it's Lombok annotation: https://projectlombok.org/features/Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Movie implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue 
    private Integer id;

    private String title;

    private Integer yearOfRelease;       

    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "genre")
    private List<Genre> genres;

    public Movie(String title, Integer yearOfRelease, List<Genre> genres) {
        this.title = title;
        this.yearOfRelease = yearOfRelease;
        this.genres = genres;
    }
}

public enum Genre {
    ACTION, COMEDY, ...;
}

public interface MovieRepo extends JpaRepository<Movie, Integer> {
}
```

In this case you create your movie like this:

```
Movie movie = new Movie("Title", 2000, Arrays.asList(ACTION, COMEDY));
movieRepo.save(movie);
```

Second variant - 'genre' as independent entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Movie implements Serializable {
    // the same as previous one...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Genre> genres;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor 
@Entity
public class Genre implements Serializable {
    @Id private String name;

    public Genre(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

public interface MovieRepo extends JpaRepository<Movie, Integer> {
}

public interface GenreRepo extends JpaRepository<Genre, String> {
}
```

In this case you first create genres:

```
List<Genre> genres = genreRepo.saveAll(Arrays.asList(
   new Genre("Action"),
   new Genre("Comedy"),
));
```

Then create movie:

```
Movie movie = new Movie("Title", 2000, genres);
movieRepo.save(movie);
```

More info to read: [Hibernate ORM User Guide - Collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections)